# How can I download apps again after changing my Google account password?

Tags: google-play-store, google-account

I changed the password for my Google account earlier, and since then, every attempt to install an app results in a download was unsuccessful error. I have not been prompted for my new password anywhere, so this is highly likely to be the problem. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot remove the "main" account that is linked to your market account, at least I have never been able to when I tried.

I would try rebooting the device, then turn off all "syncing" for that account. I would even reboot again after turning it off. Then turn syncing back on.

*[edit]*
I've also read that someone did the following:

- Changed Password via web browser
- Opened gmail application
- hit Menu -> Refresh
- The refresh will fail, but there will be a notification to enter new password.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your version, try going into home -> menu -> settings -> Accounts & sync.

You may need to remove and re-add your Google login as I don't see any option to change the password (in v2.3).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try using the Gmail app and see if that triggers the password re-entry.

Comment: I have, it did, didn't carry over to Market.

Comment: @Macha Ah. I would try clearing the data for the Market app now that the device has picked up the change.